# Error 500 on apply promo rule category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I found what it seems a bug inside Magento (1.9.3.0). When i create a new promotion on my catalog, then I apply it on a category it work.

But if this rule is in relation with some product on customer cart, then this customer have an error 500 on all the website. It seems to be an infinite loop or something like that.

I try to disable all my custom module, same, but when I disable Mage_Checkout, it work again.

I found this : http://ka.lpe.sh/2015/03/28/magento-checkout-cart-500-error/ but don't work for me, same with the "patch" on comments : https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/54529dadb0bc01a62a2d

Have you some clue or better : solution ? :)

Thanks

Comment: Please share the error message. This way it's only guessing.

Comment: Actually I don't have any error message. My apache log don't have more line after that error and the client side browser just crash with a reset connexion.

Answer (score 0):

Check error log or enable error reporting. To enable error reporting, do following steps:

In Index page change the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Set `$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true`

and uncomment this line

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

After getting exact error, it can be solved.

Comment: there is only a timeout, a death lock in loop or something like that happen I think, there is no real "error", no throw, no php crash (except the timeout).